# Kendo TreeList command 'visible' not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

`visible` is not working within command in Kendo TreeList (Kendo UI JQuery).

```js
{
    command: [
        {
            imageClass: "k-i-info",
            name: "details",
            text: "Details",
            visible: function (dataItem) { 
                return dataItem.LastName.charAt(0) !== "D" 
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. It is not part of the API. See https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist/configuration/columns.command

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, the `DataBound`-event may help you: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist/events/databound